# vscode - close debug console when debugging is done

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to automatically close the debug console when debugging is done? Right now it stays open with the text 'Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.'

Answer (score 11):

VSCode 1.42 now has a setting for that use case:

See "[**Setting to hide Debug Console after debugging**](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/873656bd7d00ce880ccb056a67e2b677331f3a3f/release-notes/v1_42.md#setting-to-hide-debug-console-after-debugging)"

> A new setting **`debug.console.closeOnEnd`** has been introduced that controls whether the debug console should automatically close after debugging has stopped.

---

VSCode 1.69 (June 2022) will improve that, following [issue 148616](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/148616) and [PR 151535](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/151535):

> ### Respect debug.console.closeOnEnd setting even when the debug console has been moved to another view.
>
> Close whichever view container contains the debug console.

It avoids seeing the debug view collapsed instead of closed:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/47410353/166419264-0fcbda3a-c15e-405d-a790-360f3270e148.png]

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop, to move it back to the top...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just Right click on it and click on 'Reset Location'. It will be restored to its original location.